# Creating records using macro in Clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

I want to define a vector with all the values i want to use in my record and then pass this vector to a macro that creates my record.

```
(def keys ['data1 'data2 'data3])

(defmacro make-record  [n v & body] `(defrecord ~n ~v ~@body))
(make-record VUD vud-keys)
(macroexpand-1 '(make-record TYPE keys)) -> (defrecord TYPE keys)
```

What is want is:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(make-record TYPE keys)) -> (defrecord TYPE ['data1 'data2 'data3])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to evaluate your arguments during macroexpansion.
This is what `eval` does.

```
(def keys '[data1 data2 data3])
(defmacro make-record [name keys]
  `(defrecord ~name ~(eval keys)))
```

Comment: That `eval` is needed for such a simple purpose disturbs me.  Much about macros does, though.